# MS-Access: Text column transformations to clean data with no unique ID

Tags: ms-access, data-cleaning

I have about ten data sources I'm trying to aggregate in an Access DB to feed a set of Tableau dashboards. The files all contain employee data, the problem is, `Employee_Name` is inconsistent across the files, and only one file has a unique ID, so I can't perform any of the joins I need to.

The best solution is of course to get the source data with a common `Employee_ID` across all files, but I don't know if/when I can get that.

Currently, the name formats are as follows

```
FISHER, BOBBY M
FISHER BOBBY
FISHER, BOBBY M L
Fisher, Bobby M
Fisher Bobby M
Bobby M Fisher
Bobby Fisher
Bobby  Fisher (note: two spaces)
Fisher Bobby M Jr. 

And just to make it really fun:
Fisher, Bob Jr.
```

So all these names are equivalent, and all join under the same `Employee_ID` if that existed.

I know I can write an expression like `StrConv(Replace(Replace([Employee Name],",",""),".",""),3)` to handle some of the inconsistencies, but even if I do that for every table, it still won't catch Bob and Bobby, and I still have to string split and concatenate to end up with a "somewhat" robust, consistent `Employee_Name` to join on.

I could create a lookup table for each table to assign a unique ID, but that's a terrible solution as soon as you start adding more people to the original data.

Does anyone have any other ideas on how to approach this, or do I really just need to insist that I get the unique IDs, and that otherwise a sustainable solution isn't really possible.

Comment: Names make terrible unique identifiers. Insist on some other unique ID. Fix the data.

Comment: And name parts should be in separate fields.

Answer (score 0):

Here is where I would start: Remove all dots commas and extra spaces, then split the name into substrings and keep the two longest ones. That is your First and Last name, hopefully. Compare each checking for the reversals `(StringA1=StringA2 AND String B1=StringB2) OR (StringA1=StringB2 AND String B1=StringA2)`. That should get you all the matches for full first and last name.

Depending on the size of your data, there may be a small enough remainder of unresolved matches to be done manually. If not you have to start checking things like `StringA1 LIKE "*" & StringA2 & "*"` instead of equality.

As long as the goal is to do as much as possible with code and fix the rest manually, that should get you almost there. If you want a fully automated, repeatable process you are probably better off waiting for the full original data.